# Android - Idle time?

Tags: android

How to know the idle time for an android device?

Idle time is the time where human interaction is last made with the device (touch on screen or keyboard click)

Partial or full code is very much appreciated.

Comment: No we won't write your code for you. And unless you mean to do this within the context of your app, this is most likely not possible without custom firmware.

Comment: sorry but if your here to fire on other people don't come contribute. I am learning some development in android and help will be much appreciated on this matter. As many are looking for the same thing

Comment: `A full working code is very much appreciated`. No we won't write your code for you.

Comment: thanks for your kind comment, a piece of code is also appreciated or guideline for the solution as well. not nice welcome for a newcomer..esp when you down vote:)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could do this by implementing an AccessibilityService.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Activity.onUserInteraction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29), I use it for this purpose.

Comment: What happen when the activity was closed? Is it possible to find the idle time of the device which did not get interacted?